# How to start automatically and run tomcat 6.0.37 version as a background process on Remote Desktop Server start up?

Tags: windows, tomcat

Currently I am running tomcat 6.0.37 version (64-bit windows) on remote desktop server(OS-Windows2008/64-bit), please help me to find answers for the following questions.

**QUESTIONS**

**Q1)** How can I run tomcat 6.0.37 version(64-bit windows) as a background process, after closing the tomcat server command prompt window?

(Note : "Tomcat windows service Installer" is not applicable for my scenario.)

**Q2)** How to start Tomcat 6.0.37 version(64-bit windows) automatically when remote desktop server(OS-Windows2008/64-bit) starts up and also when remote desktop server(OS-Windows2008/64-bit) gets restarted?

Please help me regarding the above questions with step-by-step procedure and some useful information regarding above questions.

Thanks,

Ashwini

Comment: Why can't you install Tomcat as a service?

Comment: Thomas, I am running "Openbravo ERP(3.0MP27v) tool". According to Openbravo user manual, i am not suppose to install(or run) Tomcat(6.0.37v) as a service.So, please help me regarding above questions without installing Tomcat as a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution on "How to start automatically and run tomcat 6.0.37 version as a background process on Remote Desktop Server start up?"

Step 1: In Environment Variables, set variable name and variable value as
        CATALINA_HOME  and C:\Tomcat6

Step 2: Environment Variables, set variable name and variable value  as
        CATALINA_OPTS and  -server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms384M -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=5750M(according to usage of your RAM size)

Step 3: Once installed tomcat service installer by setting the username = xyz, password= xyz and role=xyz-gui,manager-gui.

Then, in right corner of your desktop screen will get a Tomcat server symbol to start and stop the service. Right click on the icon, choose configure---->Java tab and enter those according to your system RAM.

In Java Options text box:

-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Xms1536M
-Xmx3072M
-XX:MaxPermSize=5750m(according to ur RAM size)

And set the values of:

Initial Memory Pool = 64MB

Maximum memory Pool = 5750(usage of RAM Size)

Thread Stack Size = 256MB

These steps are working perfectly for me. Tomcat service is running successfully without any problems.

Thanks,

Ashwini

Answer (score 0):

The short version is you can't. The problems you are describing are exactly the type of problems running as a service is meant to solve.

I can't think of any valid reason why a web application couldn't run as a service. I'd challenge the supplier of your application as to why they are making such a claim.

Meanwhile, I'd run Tomcat as a service anyway. If the app needs access to network shares then you'll need to run the service as a domain user with access to those shares and make sure you specify them using the full UNC path rather than mapped drives.

Comment: Hi Thomas,
  
  I have installed the "tomcat service installer6.0.31(64-bit)" and the tomcat server started successfully.
But after adding the openbravo folder into c:\Tomcat6\webapps\openbravo
i am getting an error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space".

Path set in Enviornment variable as below,
  CATALINA_OPTS = -server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms384M -Xmx1536M -

XX:MaxPermSize=256M

Please help me regarding the above issue.


Thanks,
Ashwini

Comment: Why did you install 6.0.31 rather thsn the latest? Try increasing PermGen. When I see PermGen faiures on startup I generally double it each time until Tomcat starts so the next value I'd try is -XX:MaxPermSize=512M

Comment: Hi Thomas,

   I have installed "apache tomcat service installer 7" and also changed the value of -XX:MaxPermSize=256M to -XX:MaxPermSize=512M and also doubled the values till upto -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M 
But now i am getting an exception in tomcat as: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

(Note: After deploying the openbravo folder in C:\Tomcat\webapp\openbravo, then in tomcat web application manager, "/openbravo" path running as false)


Please help me the regarding the above exception


Thanks, 
Ashwini

Comment: That should really be in a new question and you'll need to provide the full stacktrace.